# Testing minified javascript

Tags: javascript, minify

Should we test the minified versions of our javascript files as we develop them, or is it an extremely low risk that the minified javascript does not differ in function from the un-minified version?

Answer (score 7):

Running your test suites against them should be enough.

...

You *do* have test suites... right?

Comment: You caught me!  Do you have any pointers to resources for writing js test suites, especially code that makes use of jquery to manipulate the dom, handle events, etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately JavaScript is one of the languages that I've not had to write a test suite for yet. JSUnit looks promising though. http://www.jsunit.net/

Comment: I've used JSSpec in the past, and it seems like JSUnit has been deprecated in favor of https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine

Answer (score 4):

Run them through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) before minifying them and if they pass that they should minify without a problem. The key here is to not forget a ; since minifying will remove all linefeeds. Also declaring variables helps the minifying process, but not doing so will not break anything by minifying.

Comment: Also try to avoid the `a + ++b` type of stuff, as suggested here (in the caution part): http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any of my scripts behaving differently so far after minifying them but sill i do test them before making them public just to make sure everything has been done correctly.

And you are supposed to sort of test it before using/making it public just to make sure that it works the way you wanted.

If you have done everything correctly in non-minified version, it should be not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you minify with. Closure Compiler and YUI Compressor fully tokenize and parse scripts and tend to handle almost anything most browsers will accept. JSMin (particularly [modified versions](http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/branches/2.1.4/min/lib/JSMin.php)) are mostly reliable, but stay away from anything regex-based.

Agreed on svinto's advice.